# How to custom fairseq model input?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, machine-translation

I am using [pytorch/fairseq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq) for create a seq2seq translation model that use src_tokens and its postag as input to improve machine translation result in a way that describe in this [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/U16-1001). I'm already custom preprocess.py file to preprocess tag file but still confuse about how fairseq model receives input. Please explain me about how fairseq model receives input and give me some idea about how to make model receive postag and src tokens as tensor. Thanks